# What does this statement mean?

Tags: java, collections, set

I am a beginner in Java and do not understand what **`if(!s.add(a))`** means in this code excerpt:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
for(String a:args) {
    if(!s.add(a)) System.out.println("Duplicate detected:"+a);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if collection s already has item a, then the add method will return false.  The ! is a "not" operator, turning that false into true.  So, if the item is already in the collection, you will see the println result.

Comment: Also written, if(s.add(a) == false))

Answer (score 10):

[`add`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) is specified in the [`Collection` interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) to return a `boolean` indicating whether the addition was successful. From the Javadocs:

> Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element.)

This code prints out a message if the addition was unsuccessful, which happens when there is a duplicate in the set.

Answer (score 3):

s.add() will return a boolean depending on whether the item was added to the collection (true) or not (false)

Answer (score 2):

The add method returns a boolean indicating whether or not the add succeeded. Might be clearer with indenting:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
for(String a:args)
    if(!s.add(a))
        System.out.println("Duplicate detected:"+a);
```

Or even better with braces:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
for(String a:args) {
    if(!s.add(a)) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate detected:"+a);
    }
}
```

The message is displayed if the add failed.

Comment: Have fixed indentation, and added the {} version (don't forget it's not my code...)

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, add returns a boolean indicating whether a has been added to the set.
Its equivalent to

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
for(String a:args) {
    if (s.contains(a)){
      System.out.println("Duplicate detected:"+a);
    }
    else{
       s.add(a);
    }
}
```

From the [javadoc for the Set interface.](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

> ```
> contains
>
> boolean contains(Object o)
>
>      Returns true if this set contains the specified element.
>      More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains
>      an element e such that (o==null ? e==null :o.equals(e)).
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`s.add(a)` will only add `a` to the set if it is not already contained in the set (by equality). The `add` method returns `true` iff the operation causes the set to be modified.

hence if a was already in the `Set`, the `add` method would **not** add it again, therefore **not** modify the set, therefore return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Adds the specified element to this set
>   if it is not already present
>
> If this set already contains the
>   element, the call leaves the set
>   unchanged and returns false.

Answer (score 0):

"!" is the symbol for 'NOT'.

Read it as:

'if not add argument a to hashset s, then...'

OR

'if adding argument a to hashset s returns false, then...'

Answer (score 0):

The Set data structure can only contain unique values.

The method add(Object) will return false if the object could not be added (i.e. It is a duplicate entry).

The method will return true if the object was added to the set.

Answer (score 0):

No Set object allow duplicates. The HashSet object don't allow duplicates too, but the get() method ( put() and contains() too ) runs in constant time O(k) so it's a good way to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Presented for your consideration:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class s1 {
    public static final boolean DUPLICATE = false;
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();

        if (!s.add("Hello Bub")) System.out.println("Duplicate detected(1)");

        if (s.add("Hello Bub") == DUPLICATE) System.out.println("Duplicate detected(2)");
    }
}
```

Which seems clearer?